# Get mouse position without being on main form

Tags: java, swing

How do i get mouse position coordinates without being in form?

Im using this code to get position:

```
int x =getMousePosition().x;
int y=getMousePosition().y;
jTextCoordenadaRatoX.setText(String.valueOf(x));
jTextCoordenadaRatoY.setText(String.valueOf(y));
```

If i execute this code without being on "main form" the code above doesnt work.

Thank you.

Comment: *If i execute this code without being on "main form" it blows up.*. Looks like you've got a few safety issues there..

Comment: can you define - "blows up" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this should be possible by calling `getLocation()` on the `PointerInfo` that can be obtained with [MouseInfo#getPointerInfo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html#getPointerInfo%28%29)

(Why your code "blows up", as you called it, is not obvious as long as nobody knows what `getMousePosition()` does (and what "blowing up" means - hopefully, nobody got hurt, at least))

EDIT: Well, I guess "blows up" means that it throws a `NullPointerException` because `getMousePosition()` returns `null`, but one would have to see its implementation to be sure